# PowerMockito execption for doNothing for a private method

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, powermockito, private-methods

I have a class which has two private methods I am writing JUnit for one method test() and want the other method test1 to do nothing. It's like this..the method I want to call is test() and i want when it is called the test1() which is called it does nothing as

```
class foo{

private void test1() {

//some code;
}

private int test( Element e){

test1(element e);

return 0;
}
}
```

my test class is like this...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Foo.class)

public class FooTest {

private Foo foo= new Foo;

public void testTest() {

element e;

Foo testOb= PowerMockito.spy(foo);

PowerMockito.doNothing().when(testOb, "test1", Matchers.any(Element.class));

 PowerMockito.doCallRealMethod().when(testOb, "test", e);

}
```

Now the problem i am facing that it is showing an exception

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer(PowerMockitoCore.java)
E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.

Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();

now if i remove the "PowerMockito.doNothing().when(testOb, "test1", Matchers.any(Element.class));" line then it works fine but adding this produces the exception can anyone please help me..
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the method you are mocking gets a value returned,I dont see you returning a value when you are mocking the class ,the powermockito framework is expecting a return value when mocked , however I havent seen you sending a mock value , try with a return mock value in the class .

Comment: the method i am mocking which is returning a value will return a value because the the real method will be called there despite me returning anything using power mock.. The issue with the second method which will not return anything and the doNothing() line throws exception there.. without that line it runs just fine.. But i have to mock that method too...

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of doNothing is wrong.

Mockito.doNothing().when(mockedObject).Method();